# Managed Property of type YesNo - Sharepoint Online (Office365)

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, office-365, managed-property

In Sharepoint Online (Office365 post-update) I created a custom managed property mapped to a custom crawled property. Both the source field and the managed property are set to type Yes/No.  The managed property is also set to Queryable and Retrievable (but not searchable).

I have been unable to create a search query that returns any records using this managed property. I have tried all combinations of =false and = no, with and without quotes, operators = and :, etc.

I am able to query on other managed properties using :, but can't find a functional syntax for yes/no properties.

I tried posting my question in the Office365 SP forums, but they directed me here.  I'd appreciate if someone could please provide the correct syntax for a query on a yes/no managed property. Ultimately I'd like to set it up as a results source. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE (YourProperty LIKE '1')` should get you the result you want, use `1` for "TRUE" and `0` for "FALSE"